# Change Eclipse Project Settings programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a rather big project with about 30 seperate subprojects hosted on subversion. If I want to set up the project on a new client, i have to check out 30 projects (each time manually selecting the trunk), then change the eclipse facette for each project and then convert every project into a plugin project. Finally I have to build the project using maven.

Is there an easier way to do this? Perhaps some kind of API provided by eclipse which allows me to change project settings without fiddling with the `.settings` and `.classpath` files?

Comment: Do you means these projects are Eclipse Plugin projects? Are these subprojects related like it sounds? May be it might be better to create a multi-module build from it? Than you can checkout a single trunk and import that trunk into eclipse.

Comment: I am working with osgi, so most of the projects are plugin projects. but i think i have to look how i can do this with maven. still, setting facets and so on for workin with eclipse still has to be done manually

Comment: Do you check-in the .project file?

Comment: Yup. I do check the project file in.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that you are missing some of the project metadata files from your source control system. There should be no reason for performing these steps every time you pull down these projects.

Check to make sure that all files starting with '.' in project root are in source control along with the entire contents of the `.settings` directory.